# django, how to mapping no other address, but just domain?

Tags: python, django

**myproject/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('website-app.urls', namespace='website')),
]
```

**website-app/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.somedef, name='somename')
]
```

I want to connect url `domain.com/` to `views.somedef` which is not in myproject.

What `domain.com/` means is just `domain` and end of address with `/`.

It is with No other parameters.

`domain.com/other/parameters/` has other parameters (`other/parameters/`), so it is not what I want.

If I run django with that above code, django says 
`?: (urls.W001) Your URL pattern '^$' uses include with a regex ending with a '$'. Remove the dollar from the regex to avoid problems including URLs.`

Is there any good way to use url `domain.com/` in `website-app/urls.py` ,

Not in `myproject/urls.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

**myproject/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('website-app.urls', namespace='website')),
]
```

**website-app/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'$', views.somedef, name='somename')
]
```